# Copy data from Redshift To MySQL/PSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, etl, amazon-redshift

I tried searching for it but couldn't find out...

What is the best way to copy data from Amazon Redshift to MySQL/PSQL Database ?

Only solution I know of is to copy data from Redshift to my machine and then move it to MySQL/PSQL but that of course, is I/O intensive and not scalable.

Can anyone please suggest something better (may be something via S3) ?

Comment: So you do not want this process to happen via a host/machine?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways you can do that:

1. Use UNLOAD command of Redshift to export and upload table data into S3. Then import them into your psql/ MySQL tables using the AWS S3 SDK(maybe using Python/ Java)
2. Use AWS Data Pipeline to create dataflows to export Redshift data and import them into your choice of databases
3. Use AWS SDKs to programmatically export Redshift data using Python/ Java/ Ruby and import the data back into your databases.

Comment: As per the 1st solution, we can copy data from S3 to MySQL/PSQL tables using AWS S3 SDK. I tried looking out for such an API in AWS S3 SDK but could not find it...
If any such API is available, can you please point me to it...
Thanks

Comment: If going with Python, You can use S3 Boto to access files in S3 and use any pySQL or psyCOPG to load data into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what AWS Data Pipeline is built for.  Please have a look at our working sample for accomplishing what you want to do:

https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/tree/master/samples/RedshiftToRDS

Comment: Sadly this is not (as of Feb 2020) something available across all regions. So the question remains valid.